# getBoundingClientRect retorna valores diferentes

Tags: javascript, react

Estou criando um botão em React que ao clicar gera um efeito *ripple*. Utilizo o `getBoundingClientRect` para pegar a posição, mas quando faço um clique do mouse muito rápido no mesmo lugar, as coordenadas mudam e o efeito aparece de forma aleatória no botão.

Como faço para pegar as coordenadas exatas com cliques no mesmo lugar?

```js
import React from 'react';

import { Button } from './styles'

const ReactButton = ({ children }) => {

  const renderEffect = event =>{
    const button = event.currentTarget;

    const circleEffect = document.createElement('span');
    const proportion = Math.max(button.clientWidth, button.clientHeight);

    const radius = proportion / 2;


    const rect = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    
    
    circleEffect.style.width = `${proportion}px`;
    circleEffect.style.height = `${proportion}px`;

    circleEffect.style.left = `${Math.trunc(event.clientX - rect.left - radius) }px`;
    circleEffect.style.top = `${Math.trunc(event.clientY - rect.top - radius) }px`;

    
    circleEffect.classList.add('drop')

    const drop = button.getElementsByClassName('drop')[0];

    if(drop) {drop.remove()};

    button.appendChild(circleEffect);

  }

  return (
      <Button onClick={renderEffect}>
          {children}
      </Button>
      )
  
}

export default ReactButton;
```

```js
import styled, { keyframes } from 'styled-components'


const drop = keyframes`
  to {
    transform: scale(4);
    opacity: 0;
  }

`

export const Button = styled.button`
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #EA5E45;
  transition: background 400ms;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  outline: 0;
  border: 0;
  /* border-radius: 0.20rem; */
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5rem rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  cursor: pointer;

  span.drop {
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: scale(0);
    animation: ${drop} 600ms linear;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  }

`;
```

Comment: Talvez `event.target` na segunda vez seja o `circleEffect` que você adicionou a primeira vez, tente fazer um `console.log` para verificar se o `event.target` é realmente o que você espera que seja. Algo como `console.log(event.target.tagName)` talvez já de para verificar isso.

Comment: Realmente @IcaroMartins. Retornei duas vezes a mesma tag button ocasionando esse conflito. MUITO OBRIGADO MEU CARO. Deixei assim irmão:

Math.trunc(event.clientX - button.getBoundingClientRect().left - radius)

Comment: Que bom que ajudou de alguma forma =D, então agora para não deixar sua pergunta aberta você pode: responder sua pergunta mostrando qual era o problema e qual foi a solução, deleta-la ou se ainda houver algum problema atualizar ela clicando em [edit].

Comment: está misturando comandos diferentes daqueles que o `React` utiliza ... não vai ser legal isso e vai te trazer muitos problemas

Comment: Consegui resolver com a dica do amigo. Valeu pela enorme força

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução foi retirar o

```
const rect = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
```

e manter só a utilização do com o event.currentTarget.